# Excel: Array formula to return the column data that matches multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, criteria

I would like to submit an Excel problem I tried to solve for the past few days. I am not allowed to use macro, only formulas.

I have 3 tables (see link):

- The first one (purple) contain a list of employees and their initials, no duplicates;
- The second one (blue) is the main database (+ 500 columns), where all the employees codes are reported and each check mark (ü) represent the specific options related to that employee; this table is always modified (employees come and go, options are added, etc.);
- The third one (Green) is the table that we need to make functional; when we select the name of an employee (yellow), it returns the matching initials (orange); we would like this table to automatically search the initials of the employee in the blue table heading and return the Codes that match the check marks in the respective column; I need a particular array formula to do so.

As you can notice, I calculated various formulas tests and, although I might be on the right path, I lack the necessary skills to create a complex formula that will return the matching codes of the preferences (check marks) from the array column. Does someone have an idea what should be modified to achieve this goal ? Thank you all for any solution you can propose.

[Excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GTOmYCNk50PHeuTQtB3ySd5i_cu56-8K9sXtW56lyHY/edit#gid=1245981272)

Comment: Your sample worksheet is locked as private (requires permission) but this is probably just a duplicate of one of the array [tag:textjoin] questions anyways.

Comment: You are right, can you please use this link :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GTOmYCNk50PHeuTQtB3ySd5i_cu56-8K9sXtW56lyHY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am checking your textjoin link right now, thank you. I can guess from the titles that the subject may not correspond to what I seek, but they might offer a solution I could use.